# Android error : Could not find instantapps.jar (com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.1.0)

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to build my Android project again after having switched from my previous computer. The project contains an APK and an instant app.

I have fetched all the source code from Git, but when trying to Make Project, I'm getting this error:

[image]

Any idea? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried a brand new project and test 1.1.0? I haven't run into this issue. Have you also tried "Invalidate Caches / Restart" ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like  **`jcenter()`** issue.

> [**`JCenter`**](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) is a java repository, which is the largest repository in the
>   world for Java and Android OSS libraries, packages and components. All
>   the content in JCenter is served over a CDN, with a secure HTTPS
>   connection.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

If the same problem arises, use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.0.0'
```

Comment: @Someday Clean-Rebuild-Sync

Comment: Nope... I tried with `compile 'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.0.0'` instead and it builds fine... it looks like something is wrong with `instantapps:1.1.0`

Comment: @Someday looks like a valid issue there. By the way, use `implementation` instead of `compile`.

Comment: Yes I should change this. Thanks for your answer, what do I have to do then?

Comment: @Someday Read https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa

Comment: Oh no sorry, I was talking about this `1.1.0` issue, what should I do about it? Thanks anyway for the link!

Comment: @Someday Seems like we are missing some setup issue or it's a bug from their end. So for that case use `1.0.0` now